# What does it mean that a partial derivative exists

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Let's say I have a function $F(x,y)= 3x^2 + 9y^2$,
do third order partial derivatives exist for this function?

Partial derivatives of the first order exist,
second order derivatives also exist, for example $d^2F/dx^2 = 6$

Question is do further orders exist?, is saying that $d^3F/dx^3=0$ correct?
can this continue further?

Does anything change when we calculate the derivative at a particular point like $(0,0)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at the definition of a partial derivative, in this case for a function $F$ of two variables,
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x,y) = \lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{F(x+h,y)-F(x,y)}{h}} $$
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(x,y) = \lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{F(x,y+h)-F(x,y)}{h}} $$
When we say that a partial derivative of $F$ exists at a point $(x,y)$, we are saying that the above limit exists. In the case you mentioned, we take  higher-and-higher order partial derivatives with respect to $x$ until,
$$\frac {\partial ^{n}F}{\partial x ^{n}}=0$$
For some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. We know that the next partial derivative exists since the limit,
$$\frac {\partial ^{n+1}F}{\partial x^{n+1}}(x,y) = \lim_{h \to 0}{\frac {0-0}{h}}$$
Exists and is equal to $0$.

Comment: What might be confusing about your answer to some readers is that you talk about taking the derivative at a point $(x,y)$, then seem to suggest that because the partial derivative is zero *there*, the higher-order partial derivative will be also. But it's only because the partial derivative becomes the zero function, not just zero at the point, that we know immediately that all high-orders partial derivatives are the zero function also.

Answer (score 0):

1)Higher order partial derivatives are similar to higher order derivatives,they become  zero  for algebraic function after differentiating for a finite number of times.

2)yes ,saying that the third order partial derivative is zero holds a meaning ,it's a bit confusing to understand what it means ,it's the rate at which the change in velocity is changing (or the rate of change of acceleration) in terms of physics ,in math,it's the rate of change of change in slope ,it's a bit trivial to try to understand the meaning of higher order derivatives  ,upto what I have learnt ,a third order derivative isn't as beautiful as second order and first order derivatives ,first order and second order derivatives are important in vector calculus ,Try searching Divergence ,Curl and Laplacian ,they are made of first and second order derivatives ,they help us to know new things about curves ,scalar fields ,vector fields etc ,first and second order derivatives provides sufficient information about the curve ,higher order derivatives helps us to enhance our understanding .

I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't know what you mean that higher order derivatives "cease to exist for algebraic function after differentiating for a finite number of times". Polynomials in particular are analytic functions - they are infinitely differentiable.

Comment: They do not "cease to exist", rather we say they "vanish" ... which just means they equal zero.  Zero exists.

Comment: I meant they become zero

Comment: Oh, ok, I recommend editing your answer.